# Australia - Arriving with prescription drugs (birth control)

Tags: international-travel, health, australia, drugs

I'm going to move to Australia 2 months from now and my wife has some concerns about taking a pack with 6 months worth of birth control pills. Reason why is we'll have plenty of stuff to care about in our first 6 months and not having to look for a doctor right away would be awesome.

Problem is i'm not being able to find a reliable source which tells me if she can do that.

Some websites that i've seen stated that she would be able to take her pills **IF** she took a translated prescription from her doctor, while others state that she **won't be able** to take them at all.

So, has any woman around here ever been through that ?
Thanks.

Comment: This question might be better suited to Expats SE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the Government of Australia's website, which would be more reliable than some blogger, you can bring a three month supply along with a English version of the prescription.

http://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Ente/Brin/Can-I-bring-it-back/Can-I-Bring-It-Back-Medicine/Can-I-Bring-Medicine-Back

*(do you think their web guru could have packed any more seo keywords in that url?)*